# test IAP in debug mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know Apple support 2 links for IAP, one for debug one for release, I built my app to my device on debug mode, and used `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` to buy a IAP product, but the device always show me a alert with **[Environment:Sandbox]**.

what I want to know is: **can I test iap through true store(`https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt`) not sandbox store.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not test it through the actual appstore on the debug mode.